# To test a picker in robotium

Tags: android

I want to test a simple picker in Robotium. Is there any way through which i can test a picker in my test case directly or indirectly?

Answer (score 0):

Robotium allows you to set a picker, for example a DatePicker, with the following way

```
solo.clickOnButton(0);
solo.setDatePicker(0, year, month, day);
solo.clickOnButton("Set");
```

Hope this helps.  There is a simular method for the time picker called

```
solo.setTimePicker(0, hours, minutes);
```

Hope this helps.